# sessions in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i am developing a videos website  in that one fo the web page where videos are playing where i place the option sending mail to friends where link of the video will go. Problem is the videos play on videoid which is in session. so when i send mail that is link how can i send videoid which is in session how can i send session["videoid"]. can u help me thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using querystring parameters to transmit your video ids.

If, for some reason, you can't modify the play video page, you can create a new page that takes a video id as a querystring parameter, loads session["videoid"] with that parameter value, and redirects to the play video page.  You can then embed links to this new page in your email messages.

Comment: To build on this - don't send the real video id.  Make a GUID for the video ID.  Make a new table that will relate a GUID to the real video id, and when the video is loaded, check that the GUID is valid.  This way you can manage the video better - like... making a video link expire after a certain amount of time, as an example.